# React native camera package causing build to fail

Tags: react-native, kotlin, gradle, camera

Unable to find much info on this.

We have a standard React-native CLI project.
Versions

- React: 18.2.0
- ReactNative: 0.71.1

None of the configuration files have been edited from default as far as i'm aware.

We have added the following npm package to access and manage camera usage
`npm install react-native-vision-camera`

Without importing the package anywhere in the app. The build is now failing with the following outputs.[image]

I've tried various npm camera packages, they have all suffered similar issues.
If I uninstall the package. The app builds fine again.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell this package to use the correct Kotlin version. Try to add the following lines to your `android/build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        // For @react-native-community/netinfo package
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"

        kotlin_version = '1.6.20'    // <-- Add this
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.20'     // <-- Add this
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
```